# 500 Internal Server Error when manually reloading main page in Next.js app deployed on Vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel

I have deployed a Next.js app on Vercel and am experiencing a 500 Internal Server Error when manually reloading the main page. The error occurs only on main page and when I reload the page manually, not when I navigate to it from other pages in the app.

Everything works fine on other pages but main page I can only access when I navigate to it from other pages.

I've seen similar questions online. Still, I didn't find any helpful solutions.

I have checked the server logs and have not found any obvious errors or issues. I have also checked the server-side code, including the pages/api directory, and have not found any syntax errors or other issues.

I suspect that the issue may be related to the server configuration or resource usage, but am not sure how to troubleshoot it further. I have tried upgrading the server and optimizing the code, but the issue persists.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is main index.tsx

```
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.scss";
import MainCard from "../components/MainCard";
import NormalCard from "../components/NormalCard";
import { News } from "../types/types";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { listEng } from "./category/[category]";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const LastNews = dynamic(() => import("../components/LastNews"));
const NewsBlock = dynamic(() => import("../components/NewsBlock"));
type Props = {
 news: News[];
};
export default function Home({ news }: Props) {
if (!news) {
return <div>Ведутся технічні роботи</div>;
}

return (
<div className={styles.wrap}>
  <div className={styles.upper_block}>
    <div className={styles.leftBlock}>
      <NormalCard news={news[1]} />
      <NormalCard news={news[2]} />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.middleBlock}>
      <MainCard news={news[0]} />
    </div>
    <div className={styles.rightBlock}>
      <NormalCard news={news[3]} />
      <NormalCard news={news[4]} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr className={styles.hrHome} />
  <div className={styles.titlePopular}>
    <h1>Вибір редакції</h1>
    <span>
      Тут ми зібрали три найкращі новини за останній час на розсуд нашої
      редакції. Наші журналісти працюють наполегливо, щоб надавати вам
      найактуальнішу та найцікавішу інформацію з усього світу.
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.lastNewsBlock}>
    <div className={styles.lastNews}>
      <LastNews items={news} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.newsBlock}>
    {listEng.map((category, index) => (
      <NewsBlock news={news} key={index} category={category} />
    ))}
  </div>
  </div>
 );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
let res = null;
try {
res = await axios.get(
  `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_CONNECT_URL}/api/news`
);
} catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}
return {
props: {
  news: res?.data,
},
};
};
```

Here is api

```
import dbConnect from "../../../utils/dbConnect";
import {NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse} from "next";
import NewsPosts from "../../../models/NewsPosts";

export default async function handler(req:NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse){
const {method} = req
await dbConnect()

switch (method) {
    case "GET":
        try {
            const newsGet = await NewsPosts.find({published: true})
            res.status(200).json(newsGet.reverse())
        }catch (e:any) {
            res.status(500).json(e)
        }
        break;
    case "POST":
        try {
            const newsCreate = await NewsPosts.create(req.body)
            res.status(201).json(newsCreate)
        }catch (e: any) {
            res.status(500).json(e)
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }

}
```

Next Config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
reactStrictMode: true,
images: {
 domains: [process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_CONNECT_URL],
},

};
```

also I added   "main": "index.tsx", into package.json

Forgot to mention that only error in dashboard is "WARN Warning: data for page "/" is 1.58 MB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance." but I think this problem isn't what am i looking for

Comment: IT works with UseEffect, but can I somehow rewrite it so it works normal with SSR? Because UseEffect Causes other bugs

Answer (score 0):

I've found where problem is, just added `.limit(10)` in API function